# Unity3d problem with rotation of an object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ball that goes straight on the x-Axis and can go left-right on the z-Axis. So far so good but i dont want my ball to go upwards at all, so i use the constraints in the rigidbody and i lock the Y-Position, but that creates another problem, my ball wont rotate anymore.
I have tried doing that in the script and the same thing happens.
Any ideas how to solve this?
I EDIT IT. hERE IS MY CODE. I HOPE IT HELPS

```
private Rigidbody rb;
[Tooltip("How fast the ball moves left/right")]
public float dodgeSpeed;

[Tooltip("How fast the ball moves forwards automatically")]
[Range(0, 10)]
public float rollSpeed = 5;

//Stores the starting position of mobile touch events
private Vector2 touchStart;




void Start ()
{
    // Get access to our Rigidbody component
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    ray ();
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{       

    StartCoroutine (waitToStartMoving ());
}



void Movement()
{
    float horizontalSpeed = 0;

    /*// Check if we're moving to the side
    float horizontalSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * dodgeSpeed;

    Vector3 movementForce = new Vector3(rollSpeed, 0.0f, horizontalSpeed);
    // Time.deltaTime is the amount of time since the // last frame (approx. 1/60seconds) 
    movementForce *= Time.deltaTime * 60;
    // Apply our auto-moving and movement forces 
    rb.AddForce(movementForce);
    //rb.AddForce(horizontalSpeed, 0, rollSpeed);*/


    // Check if Input has registered more than zero touches
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        // Store the first touch detected.
        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        horizontalSpeed = CalculateMovement(touch.position);

    }


    // Apply our auto-moving and movement forces
    //rb.AddForce(horizontalSpeed, 0, rollSpeed);

    var movementForce = new Vector3(rollSpeed, 0, horizontalSpeed);
    // Time.deltaTime is the amount of time since the // last frame (approx. 1/60seconds) 
    movementForce *= (Time.deltaTime * 60);
    // Apply our auto-moving and movement forces 
    rb.AddForce(movementForce);
}

IEnumerator waitToStartMoving()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (5f);
    Movement ();
}

// Will figure out where to move the player horizontally
// <param name="pixelPos">The position the player has touched/clicked on</param>
// <returns>The direction to move in the x axis</returns>
float CalculateMovement(Vector3 pixelPos)
{
    // Converts to a 0 to 1 scale
    var worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(pixelPos);
    float xMove = 0;
    // If we press the right side of the screen
    if (worldPos.x < 0.5f)
    {
        xMove = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise we're on the left
        xMove = 1;
    }
    // replace horizontalSpeed with our own value
    return xMove * dodgeSpeed;
}

void ray()
{

    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector3.down, Color.red);
    if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 5f))
    {
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
        //Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraBehaviour> ().gameOver = true;
        //GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Score>().stop = true;
        //StartCoroutine (WaitToRestart ());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can lock position but not rotation on the Rigidbody. Your provided information may not be enough to provide a suitable answer.

Comment: thats the problem i am not locking the rotation, it locks by itself everytime i check the Y position constraint.

Comment: as I said, if you were to provide the code or any additional information, you may find that an answer is easier to come by.

Comment: I EDIT IT I HOPE IT HELPS

Comment: I'm not sure if unity's physics will properly roll objects if you constrain the rigidbody so that it can't move normal to the surface.  Would it be acceptable to rotate the ball in code?

Comment: i have used the constraints again and have worked well. but now i dont know what happend. well i didnt what to jump in to code for such thing

Comment: If you decide to rotate the ball in code, you can try something like: `float rotationSpeedFactor = 0.25f;` `transform.rotation *= Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped( Quaternion.Identity, Quaternion.FromToRotation( Vector3.up, movementForce), movementForce.magnitude * rotationSpeedFactor);` after `rb.AddForce(movementForce);`.

Comment: hey Ruzihm thanks i will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my ball object 1 unit high on the Y-Axis. So when i checked the y constraint position my ball didnt touch the ground so it could rotate.Ilowered my ball at 0.8 and it worked great.
Thanks for the replies.